# Div Flutuante no Bootstrap 3 acompanhando Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Bom dia!

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
                <?php
                $hostdb = "**********";
                $userdb = "**********";
                $passdb = "**********";
                $tabledb = "**********";

                $conecta = mysql_connect($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb) or die (mysql_error());
                @mysql_select_db($tabledb, $conecta) or die ("Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados");
                mysql_set_charset('UTF8');

                $busca_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imoveisvenda WHERE imoveisvenda.dormitorio = 1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM imoveislocacao WHERE imoveislocacao.dormitorio = 1")or die(mysql_error());

                if (empty($busca_query)) {
                    echo "Nenhum registro encontrado.";
                }

                while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($busca_query)) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo "$dados[bancoimgthumb]";?>" class="img-responsive"> <?php
                echo "<b>Imóvel:</b> $dados[imovel]<br />"; 
                echo "<b>Localização:</b> $dados[localizacao]<br />"; ?>
                <p style="color:red"><b>Tipo: <?php echo "$dados[tipo]"; ?></b></p>
                <b>MAIS DETALHES:</b> <a href="<?php echo "$dados[file]"; ?>?id=<?php echo "$dados[id]";?>">Clique aqui!</a><br />
                <?php echo "<hr>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-7 banner">
                <form class="form form-inline" role="form">
                    <legend style="margin-top:1.5%;">Busca Avançada</legend> <br>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="bairro" class="col-md-6">Cidade</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select id="cidade" name="cidade" class="form-control">
                                <option>Carmo de Minas</option>
                                <option>Itamonte</option>
                                <option>Itanhandu</option>
                                <option>Passa Quatro</option>
                                <option>Pouso Alto</option>
                                <option>Soledade de Minas</option>
                                <option>São Lourenço</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="bairro" class="col-md-6">Bairro</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bairro" placeholder="Bairro">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="valor" class="col-md-6">Valor</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor" placeholder="Valor">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="dormitorios" class="col-md-6">Dormitórios</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="1"> 01 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="2"> 02 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="3"> 03 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="4"> 04 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="5"> 05
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="garagem" class="col-md-6">Garagem</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="1"> 01 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="2"> 02 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="3"> 03 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="tipo" class="col-md-6">Tipo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="residencial" name="1"> Residencial &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="checkbox" value="comercial" name="2"> Comercial &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="checkbox" value="rural" name="3"> Rural &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">Realizar Busca</button>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A div do meu lado direito, `col-md-7 banner` é uma `div` com uma "Busca Avançada". Gostaria de fazer ela acompanhar o scroll, pois a página gera uma consulta no banco de imóveis. Quero dar a opção de o usuário fazer uma busca avançada se ele quiser, em qualquer parte da página.

Já testei vários códigos, infelizmente nenhum funcionou da forma que eu queria.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Cara, sem palavras! Vou pegar pesado essa semana! Te agradeço pelo tempo dedicado, tenho aprendido muito aqui na comunidade. Te devo mais uma! Abraço e bom descanso!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você está usando Bootstrap, dê uma olhada na ferramenta `affix` http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Ela é a responsável por fazer essa `div` "Flutuante".

Aqui tem outro exemplo: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp

---

Mas lembre-se, para que este plugin funcione, é importante que, além de adicionar o css do bootstrap, você adicione também o javascript. Você pode customizar o download e fazer somente do plugin `affix` (affix + depências - ver link que passei acima).

---

#### Editado:

Dica: Você está utilizando muita tag `<br /><br />` para criar espaçamento entre os blocos do `form-group`. Não sei qual o propósito disso, mas aconselho a usar uma propriedade de margem na classe `form-group`, assim você deixa seu código mais limpo, mais fácil de fazer manutenção e tem o mesmo resultado.

```
.form-group {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0; //cima direita baixo esquerda <-- ordem dos números
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, amigo. Eu desconhecia esse recurso! Vou dar uma olhada e, ao conseguir a aplicação, posto o resultado. Abraço e bom dia!

Comment: Beleza! Editei a resposta para uma melhoria no seu código, dê uma olhada.

Comment: É verdade, amigo. Eu ainda estou montando, por isso não fiz essa implantação. Não costumo usar o [br] em quase nada. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela observação!

Comment: Consegui implantar, ficou bem tranquilo. Estou apanhando apenas porque a `div` está passando por cima do meu footer. Assim que descobrir como resolver essa pendência, vou postar o código arrumado.

Comment: Isso realmente era algo que me incomodava muito também. Ela não para de descer quando atinge o rodapé, correto? Uma solução, para pelo menos "Esconder" a parte que ficaria por cima, é definir um z-index menor que o footer, mas... Não é o correto, apenas uma alternativa.

Comment: E se eu te falar que nem o z-index tá dando certo? Mas vou achar aqui, falta pouco. Tive que tirar o formulário, tava muito grande, sem caber na tela. Mas não tem problema, coloquei um botão e um modal ao clicar, ficou bom!

Comment: Para que o `z-index` funcione é preciso ter a propriedade de `position` também configurada. Mas se você está conseguindo, ótimo!

Comment: Problema resolvido!!! Affix resolveu meu problema! Muito obrigado pelo suporte!!!

Comment: @HebertRichard não por isso! Boa sorte com os códigos =D

Comment: Vou precisar!!! kkkkk... Obrigado!